# How to automatically change plotting options for an array of plots?

Tags: plotting

I'm working with an array of plots. I'd like to change the color and the legend for each of the plots in my array. For example, working with 10 plots: I generate the empty array of plots

```
allplots =  ConstantArray[0, 10];
```

Now I want to represent them, but looping both the **color** of `PlotStyle` (I don't want all of them `Red`) and also the **legend "Code i"** (for each `i` in the iteration, a different legend number i).

With all the same, I have:

```
For[i = 0, i < 10, 
 allplots[[i]] = 
  ListLogLogPlot[alldata[[i]], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Code i"} ], i++]
```

Any ideas about how can I do it?

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need?  There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. But wait! It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 6;
alldata = RandomReal[1, {n, 100}];
colors = RandomColor[n];
```

This

```
Table[ListLogLogPlot[alldata[[i]], PlotStyle -> colors[[i]], 
  PlotLegends -> "Code " <> ToString@i], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image]

or this

```
ListLogLogPlot[Evaluate@alldata, PlotStyle -> colors, 
 PlotLegends -> Table["Code " <> ToString@i, {i, 1, n}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @corey979 is very good. Here I do basically the same, but with the following difference

- Used limited scope (Avoid global variables) with [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)
- Use [`Hue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue.html) and [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) to define the colours programmatically in order.
- Use [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) instead of [`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html)

Here is my take

```
Multicolumn[
 Module[
  {
   niterations = 9,
   data = RandomPoint[Disk[{1,1}], 1000]
   },
  Table[
   ListLogLogPlot[
    data
    , PlotStyle -> Hue[0.8 Rescale[k, {1, niterations}]]
    , PlotLegends -> {StringTemplate["Code ``"][k]}
    , PlotRange -> {{10^-3, 10}, {10^-3, 10}}
    ]
   , {k, niterations}
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there any way to choose the colors that you want? Like making an array of points? Thanks ;)

Comment: @GuillermoMartínezSomonte loo at @corey979's answer, instead of `colors = RandomColor[n];` make your own list of colours and assign it to `colors`.

Comment: Nice, I somehow didn't know about `Multicolumn`. Why `StringTemplate` instead of `<>`?

Comment: @corey979 when things become complex I find that `StringTemplate ` is more readable.